# Is it possible that an ideal generated by $S$ does not contain $S$?

Tags: ring-theory, definition, ideals

I am dealing with two differents definitions of ideals. Given a subset $S$ of a  commutative ring $A$, the ideal generated by $S$, called $\langle S \rangle $ is:

1. The smallest ideal of $A$ that contains $S$;
2. The set of the $A$-finite combinations $\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_is_i; n\in\mathbb{N}, a_i\in A, s_i\in S\}$.

My doubt is the following: can I prove that $S\subseteq\langle S\rangle $ in the second definition ***without*** the statement of $A$ has unit? I think no, for instance: $A=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\{2\}$. At the second definition I'll have $\langle S\rangle=4\mathbb{Z}$...? It looks strange for me.

Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the second definition only works if your ring has an identity.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication by $n$ is defined in any abelian group no need that $A$ is unital then $$\langle S\rangle\ =\ \{ \sum_{i=1}^I (a_i s_i+n_is_i), a_i \in A,n_i \in \Bbb{Z}, s_i \in S\}$$ is the smallest ideal of $A$ containing $S$

Comment: Great, many thanks.